# Delphi 2009, DbExpress with Oracle : Unable to load oci.dll

Tags: oracle, delphi, delphi-2009, dbexpress

i've setup a demo to test datasnap 2009, and i've got a problem with dbexpress.

The dbexpress error message, (same at design time or runtime) :
"Cannot load oci.dll library (Error code 127). The OCI.dll library may be missing from the system path."

I'm using Oracle 8.0.5. The path to oci.dll (c:\orant\BIN) is in my system path, in front of the line. I've Delphi 2005 installed too and the exact same configuration just works fine. I've moved dbexpress delphi 2005 related files, i've rebooted many times, tried to copy oci.dll in c:\windows\system or c:\windows\system32\, everytime the same error.

I'm running out of solutions. Maybe it's a problem related with the fact i've got D2005 installed too... ?

Does someone can please help me ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Here is the event log, in the IDE during build, we can see that it FOUND and LOAD OCI.dll, so the error (Cannot load oci.dll) may not be the good one :

```
Début du Thread : ID du thread : 5588. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Début du processus : C:\Documents and Settings\frplante\Mes documents\Développement\Projets\Démo DataSnap2009\Server\Server.exe. Adresse de base : $00400000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : Server.exe. Contient des infos de débogage. Adresse de base : $00400000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : ntdll.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $7C910000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : KERNEL32.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $7C800000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : OLEAUT32.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $770E0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : ADVAPI32.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $77DA0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : RPCRT4.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $77E50000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : Secur32.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $77FC0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : GDI32.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $77EF0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : USER32.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $7E390000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : msvcrt.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $77BE0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : ole32.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $774A0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : MSIMG32.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $76310000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : VERSION.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $77BD0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : COMCTL32.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $77390000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : SHLWAPI.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $77F40000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : wxvault.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $10000000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : PSAPI.DLL. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $76BA0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : MPR.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $71A60000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : detoured.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $00370000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : SHELL32.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $7C9D0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : IMM32.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $76320000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : UxTheme.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $5B090000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : **dbxora.dll**. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $00FC0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : **OCI.dll**. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $003F0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : ORA805.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01430000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : CORE40.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $015C0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NLSRTL33.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01620000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : WINMM.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $76AE0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NL80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01660000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : WSOCK32.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $71A10000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : WS2_32.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $719F0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : WS2HELP.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $719E0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : OTRACE80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01680000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NS80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $016B0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : nasns80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $016F0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : nz80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01720000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NNFG80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01770000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NNCI80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01780000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NNG80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01790000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NMP80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $017B0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NPL80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $017C0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NR80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $017D0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NT80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $017F0000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NCR80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01800000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NMS80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01840000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NNFD80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01850000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NNFN80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01860000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NI80.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01870000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : PLS805.dll. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01880000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Chargement du module : NDWSI80.DLL. Pas d'informations de débogage. Adresse de base : $01A80000. Processus Server.exe (5548)

Exception déclenchée à $7C812AEB. Classe d'exception TDBXError avec message '**Cannot load oci.dll library** (error code 127).  The oci.dll library may be missing from the system path'. Processus Server.exe (5548)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems like these usually occur if you switch Oracle Homes, but you didn't mention multiple installs.

Can you connect to Oracle using SqlPlus? [This page](http://www.embarcadero.com/jive/entry.jspa?categoryID=2&externalID=300) also recommends checking for multiple copies of oci.dll in the path (esp. windows\system32)

Comment: I've installed Oracle 10g Express Edition by the past but now it's uninstalled. How can i check if my Oracle Home are messed up ? I'm going to check the registry to ensure uninstaller didn't leave bad things

Comment: Btw i've no problems connecting with SQL+

Answer (score 1):

Windows error code 127 is a procedure not found, which perhaps means that there is an old version of the DLL, or a missing function or something,

Comment: Hi, Yes, i was wondering if it was the old version of my oci.dll, but it works with D2005

Answer (score 1):

i have problems with Oracle 10g XE Client. My fault was, that i installed multiple clients. Problem disappeared after i uninstalled them, and install the right one.

Comment: Hi, thanks, i'm goint to try to re-install myy original oracle installation

Comment: I have clean the registry from old oracle references, reinstalled Oracle 8.0.5 from scratch and still having the problem...

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with dbx oracle driver. For example it's possible, that delphi 2009 uses dbexpora.dll from D2005? Can check that?
And also try to check if it is possible to connect Oracle from Delphi 2009 using other component set, for example ADO.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i checked that, i uninstalled D2005, and i have only one version of dbxora.dll

Comment: And i have no problem connecting via ADO

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the dll into the program's root folder

Comment: sorry, I can't think of other possible solutions and don't have datasnap 2009 to test with.

Answer (score 0):

I has a similar problem with the DBXpress drivers I cant rember 100% what I did to fix it, my problem was moving it from one windows PC to another (for installation).

here is what I can remember trying

Putting the database dll in the same dir as the application along with the 3 or 4 dll from dbexpress (as the problem I was having was the dbexpress dlls (not my application) couldn't find the database dll's)

Made sure I had the correct c++ run time libs installed, as I believe the DBX drivers need this.

Updated windows to sp3 (I guess you can skip this step as your not changing computers)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on Windows Vista,  did you check that your program have access rights to oci.dll?

If not one of answers work, then you should contact CodeGear to confirm if Oracle 8.0.5 is still supported. Even Oracle in drivers does not support access to 8.0.5 for several years now. There was an article on Metalink that describes what version of server can be accessed by specific client versions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i'm running windows xp. I got the same issue with Oracle 10g XE